# How to identify ether payments from an exchange?

Tags: ether, wallets, dapps, exchanges

I am building an application that accepts payments from its users. Nowadays, only users with a wallet can make withdraws to a smart contract address(mine). This is because each user has a single and unique wallet address, so the backend is able to identify its transactions.

Nevertheless, exchanges uses the same withdraw address for most of its users so it is impossible to identify unique users transactions to my smart contract.

> Why exchanges use the same address for all the withdraws?

My solution to that would be creating a temporal wallet in my backend for each user transaction and then send the received ethers to the main wallet/smart contract.

> This solutions requires two transactions, so double fees. Is there any good alternative to that?

Comment: In addition to the account, the data transmitted with the transaction can be used to identify the recipient.

Comment: @MadJackal which data? In an exchange like Coinbase you can only send ethers to an address, you cannot execute arbitrary smart contract address neither provide callback data. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: You can incapsulate data in transactions between accounts too.

Comment: @MadJackal I don't think you can in an exchange. You can only set the value.